# What is the meaning of the characters ヨ・行ケ・ウ・行ウ・わ・ワ when written after the date?

Tags: translation, words, katakana, law

[image: examples of years with characters following]

In doing a translation, I have come across a date which has the character ヨ written in brackets after the year. I found some more cases of the same usage in what seem to be legal texts, but I still can't figure out what they mean of how to translate them. Does anyone have some insight? Do I even need to translate them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characters in brackets after the year are a special form of code which identifies a legal case as belonging to a particular category. The ヨ which you mention indicates that the case is a civil affairs case at a district court.

A more detailed list of these 事件記録符号 (case record codes) is available here:
http://home.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/hirano/nyumon/fugo2005.htm